# Creating and saving a very large list of numbers

Tags: matlab, io, numbers

How can I create the following list and save it to file without running out of memory?

```
 li = 1:2^40;
```

I know the obvious solution of creating the list and writing it to file in chunks. I wondered if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: What need does storing the list serve ?  For most purposes that I've come across generating sub-lists of natural numbers on demand is a much more elegant approach than storing all the natural numbers (or any large fraction thereof).  Think lazy evaluation of a stream representing the natural numbers rather than storage.

Comment: Certainly, using a generator would be more elegant. But, I need the entire list written to be compatible with *sigh* an older program I'm not allowed to rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that list would require 8.8 TB of memory, here's a trivial solution to prevent that from being needed:

```
loop_limit = uint64(2^40);
ii = uint64(1);
chunksize = 1000;

fid = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
while ii < loop_limit

    for jj = 1:chunksize        
        fprintf(fid, '%d\n', ii);
        ii=ii+1;
        if ii >= loop_limit
            break; end    
    end

end

fclose(fid);
```

No list is ever created anywhere; memory overhead is limited to the few variables used.

Note that the list you provided (`1:2^40`) will exceed Matlab's maximum loop index of 2147483647, which is the reason for the double loop.

Note also that this file `output.txt` would take up 8.8TB, so...better free up some harddrive space first.

Now obviously, this is absolutely mindbogglingly horrific. Can you provide more information on how the "old" program queries the file? Because I have a strong hunch that there is some bash/DOS batch trick you can use to emulate a file that contains these numbers, without actually needing the file.

Comment: The "old" program is a C++ program that reconstructs a Hidden Markov Model to represent the activity of groups of binary variables. If there are 40 variables, there are 2^40 states of population activity. It's true that a finite automaton only needs to know that it's dealing with a finite alphabet, but I don't have the time (until after my thesis) to really dig into the collaborator's code. And he's not willing to on his own.